# move a image partially out of the screen in android

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` in android. I want to move the image partially inside the screen such that only a part of the image is visible. If I set margin or padding in xml the image shrinks. I used a translate `Animation` in `onCreate` method. But I see image moving the first time the view is presented. I want the image to be partially visible without the shift being visible. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: If possible can you post your image view code?

Comment: what do you have height and width set to? If you set them to some value larger than your screen size you should be able to use margins or padding to move it where ever you please. Your Layout will have to be larger than the screen size too.

Comment: There is no imageView code. I am putting the image in xml file.

Answer (score 4):

in the parent view (like `LinearView`) set `ClipChildrens=false`, if what you are looking for

check this code, it works for me...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: negative marginTop and marginLeft did work for me. Android 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

How about this.

In your Activity's onCreate:

```
ImageView yourImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_control_id);
yourImage.setX(1000);
yourImage.setY(1000);
```

That way, it is positioned properly at startup. Or you could use an AbsoluteLayout and set the image's x and y coordinates that way. Make sure you arent using fill_parent for either the height or width.

Comment: my API is 2.1 and higher. SetX is from API 11. Isn't Absolute layout deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you use negative margins, then you can't alignParent on the opposite side, so, let's say you're trying to have the image half off on the right side of the view, you can't specify android:layout_alignParentLeft. Also, if you need the full image and don't want it to be clipped, like in the case you wanted to animate on full screen onClick, you have to set the parent layout android:clipChildren="false". The following xml def works for me:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/you_feature_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/feature_margin_right"
        android:contentDescription="feature_image"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/zero"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/zero"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/zero"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zero"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/zero"
        android:src="@drawable/feature_phone_02_2x" />
```

I'm posting this now because I just burned a few hours trying to figure this out myself, and thought maybe it'd help somebody else in the future should they come across this question like I did.